# JQuery get table row values from input and save to array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, row

I have a table with input fields inside the td. How can i get the values from the input fields (by button click) and store them into an array (one row) using JQuery ? So there are different rows with different contexts and i would like to process row by row, so i have to identify those rows by class and so on.

Thanks!

**Update:** I would like to have values from `test1` in an array, `test2` in an array and so on.

```
<tr class="test1">
 <td>
      <input type="text" name="test">
      <input type="text" name="test">
      <input type="text" name="test">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="test2">
 <td>
      <input type="text" name="test">
      <input type="text" name="test">
      <input type="text" name="test">
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you place code ? or any effort u did ?

Comment: Can you paste your code to understand better? and easily we can help you in this regard.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#button').click(function () {
  var array = [];

  $('#table tr').each(function () {
    var values = [];

    $(this)
      .find('input')
      .each(function () {
        values.push(this.val());
      });

    array.push(values);
  });
});
```

then you can take items by array.pop();

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="test1">
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="test" />
            <input type="text" name="test" />
            <input type="text" name="test" />
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="GetValues" value="GetValues" />
            </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test2">
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="test" />
            <input type="text" name="test" />
            <input type="text" name="test" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="GetValues" value="GetValues" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(".GetValues").click(function () {
    var test1 = $(this).closest(".test1").find("input:text").map(function () {

        return $(this).val();

    });

    console.log(test1)

})
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/XFy46/